# How to validate downloaded files if tests are running using GithubActions CI

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have to verify the download button works as expected and the file has downloaded, I can do validation of button but how can I verify file location if it's in CI environment?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this method: https://nodejs.org/api/os.html#os_os_homedir

It returns a string path of the current user home directory.
The default `Downloads` folder should be located in the current user directory.

Please also refer to https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/blob/master/test/functional/fixtures/regression/gh-3127/testcafe-fixtures/index-test.js. This is a test in the official TestCafe repository which solves a similar issue.